# How to show 1 form at a time on a page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating lists which contain cards that are created by the user via forms.

The issue that I'm having here is that I want to show only **1 *add-item-form* form *** on the page at a time (Not 1 form in each list but 1  form on the page overall). So, If a user creates multiple lists, then opens a form by clicking on the <kbd>Add a card</kbd> button, and then goes and click on another  <kbd>Add a card</kbd> button from another list on the page, the first form should disappear, and a new form should appear in the list that it was clicked. Right now, multiple forms are being shown in different lists when I click the <kbd>Add a card</kbd> button, especially whenever I create multiple lists.

So basically, whenever <kbd>Add a card</kbd> is clicked, if a form is already open somewhere else, it will be closed and a new form will be opened within the list that I clicked the <kbd>Add a card</kbd> button.

I hope my explanation is useful. A sample of the code is shown below.

Here's a link to the code on [Codepen][https://codepen.io/Joanc/pen/MZjJvy][1](https://codepen.io/Joanc/pen/MZjJvy).
Your help will be appreciated.

**ATTENTION**: I only want to change the cards form with class **add-item-form** not the list form with id **add-list-form**. The (grey) lists are fine, my only issue is with the cards.

```js
// *************** ADD LISTS ***************

// add new list submit eventlistener
document.getElementById("add-list-form").addEventListener("submit", addList);

function addList(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const input = document.getElementById("list-name");
  const name = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  if ('' == name) {
    return;
  }

  const list = document.createElement('div');
  list.setAttribute('class', 'list');
  list.innerHTML =
    `<div class="list-container">
    <div class="list-heading" >
      <h3 contenteditable="true">` + name + `</h3>
    <div class= "ellipsis"><a href="#">&#8230;</a></div>
    </div>
      <div> 
      <div class="link-wrapper">
      <a href="#" id="show-card-form" onclick="hideSHowForm('add-item-form', 'show-card-form');">
      <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a card</span>
      <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another card</span>
    </a>
    </div>
        <form class="add-item-form">
          <textarea placeholder="Enter a title for this card..."></textarea>
          <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Card">
          <input type="button" value="&#88;" onclick="hideSHowForm('add-item-form', 'show-card-form');">
          <div class= "ellipsis"><a href="#">&#8230;</a></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>`;

  document.getElementById("list-wrapper").appendChild(list);
}

// add new item submit eventlistener
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.add-item-form')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const textarea = e.target.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    const text = textarea.value;
    textarea.value = '';
    if ('' == text) {
      return;
    }
    //create card
    const cardItem = document.createElement('p');
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
    //create pen icon
    const pen = document.createElement('a');
    pen.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pen"></i>';
    cardItem.innerHTML = text;
    card.appendChild(cardItem)
    card.appendChild(pen);
    e.target.parentElement.prepend(card);
  }
});

let spans = document.getElementsByClassName("placeholder");
//toggle between 'add a list' and 'add another list' links
window.onload = function(){
   spans[1].style.display='none';
   document.forms[0].style.display='none';
};

let clicked = 0;
//toggle between links and 'add-list-form'
function toggleDiv(formId, linkId){
  clicked++;
  if(document.getElementById( formId ).style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementById( formId ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( linkId ).style.display = 'block';
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById( linkId ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( formId ).style.display = 'block'
  }if(clicked > 0) {
    spans[0].style.display='none';
    spans[1].style.display='block';
  }
}



//toggle between links and 'add-list-form'
function hideSHowForm(form, link){
  // var getForm = document.getElementsByClassName("listContainer");
  for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName(form).length;i++){
    // getForm[i].style.display = 'block';
      if(document.getElementsByClassName(form )[i].style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementsByClassName(form)[i].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(link).style.display = 'block';
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById(link).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName(form)[i].style.display = 'block'
  }if(clicked > 0) {
    spans[0].style.display='none';
    spans[1].style.display='block';
  }
  }
}
// function showTitleAndCardSection(){
//   var showCardSection = document.getElementsByClassName("listContainer");
//   for (var i=0;i<showCardSection.length;i+=1){
//     showCardSection [i].style.display = 'block';
//   }
//}
```

```css
/*************** ADD LISTS ***************/

.work-board {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#list-wrapper {
  margin: 8px 5px 10px 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list {
  background: transparent;
}

.list-container {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 256px;
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
  border: none;
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.list-heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.list .list-heading h3 {
  margin: 2px 3px 0px 0px;
  width: 82%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline:none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
}

.list .list-heading h3:focus{
  border: solid 2px   rgb(91,164,207);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.ellipsis {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.ellipsis:hover {
  background-color: rgba(131, 140, 145, 0.2)
}

form.add-item-form .ellipsis{
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  /* line-height:3px;  */
  text-align:center;
}

form#add-list-form { 
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 270px;
}

.form-inner-container {
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=text] {
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px   rgb(91,164,207);
  width: 247px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px   rgb(91,164,207);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 8px 13px;
  background-color: rgb(90, 172, 68);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(63, 111, 33);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 138, 53);
}

input[type=button]{
  margin-right: -5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
}

input[type=button]:hover{
  color: rgb(103,109,112);
}

form.add-item-form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

form.add-item-form textarea {
  outline: none;
  width: 92%;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.card {
  width: 92%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  min-height: 18px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}
.card:hover {
  background-color: rgba(248,249,249,0.7);
}
.card p{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card a{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fa-pen {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.fa-pen:hover {
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
}

#add-list-form, .add-item-form {
  display: none;
}

.link-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a#show-list-form {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  width: 242px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 17px;
}

a#show-list-form:hover {
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.4);
}

a#show-list-form span:first-child {
  padding-right: 172px;
}

a#show-list-form span:nth-child(2), a#show-card-form span:nth-child(2){
  display: none;   /* hides the 'Add another link' when window loads */
}
```

```html
<div class="board-wrapper">
    <div id="workBoard" class="work-board">
      <div id="list-wrapper"></div>
      <div class="link-wrapper">
        <a href="#" id="show-list-form" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');">
        <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a list</span>
        <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another list</span>
      </a>
      </div>
      <form id="add-list-form">
        <div class="form-inner-container">
        <input type="text" id="list-name" placeholder="Enter list title..." autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" value="Add List">
        <!-- <input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></input> -->
        <input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form')" value="&#88;">
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end of board-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you iterate with for loop over all `add-item-form` elements and add those styles. You add inline events listeners in `addList()` and you are not able to specify which of those elements were actually clicked, since you can't catch an event. I know how frustrating it may sound to you but I would recommend trying to write it all over again but keeping good practices. I advise you to use `innerHTML` as little you can, don't add inline styles to HTML in JS. Rather create classes that match your expectations like `shown`, `hidden`, style them and add them to events. Also use `addEventListener` instead of adding `onclick()` in HTML. You are really close to getting what you want, but its pretty messed up in this form.

Edit: The simplest workaround I can give you is this, but there is still much work to be done there:

```js
// *************** ADD LISTS ***************

// add new list submit eventlistener
document.getElementById("add-list-form").addEventListener("submit", addList);

//Declaring index
 var listIndex = 0

function addList(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const input = document.getElementById("list-name");
  const name = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  if ('' == name) {
    return;
  }
  

  const list = document.createElement('div');
  list.setAttribute('class', 'list');
  list.innerHTML =
    `<div class="list-container">
    <div class="list-heading" >
      <h3 contenteditable="true">` + name + `</h3>
    <div class= "ellipsis"><a href="#">&#8230;</a></div>
    </div>
      <div> 
      <div class="link-wrapper">
      <a href="#" id="show-card-form" onclick="hideSHowForm('add-item-form', 'show-card-form', ` + listIndex + `);">
      <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a card</span>
      <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another card</span>
    </a>
    </div>
        <form class="add-item-form">
          <textarea placeholder="Enter a title for this card..."></textarea>
          <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Card">
          <input type="button" value="&#88;" onclick="hideSHowForm('add-item-form', 'show-card-form');">
          <div class= "ellipsis"><a href="#">&#8230;</a></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>`;
  
  //Increasing index
  listIndex++
  document.getElementById("list-wrapper").appendChild(list);
}

// add new item submit eventlistener
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.add-item-form')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const textarea = e.target.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    const text = textarea.value;
    textarea.value = '';
    if ('' == text) {
      return;
    }
    //create card
    const cardItem = document.createElement('p');
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
    //create pen icon
    const pen = document.createElement('a');
    pen.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pen"></i>';
    cardItem.innerHTML = text;
    card.appendChild(cardItem)
    card.appendChild(pen);
    e.target.parentElement.prepend(card);
  }
});

let spans = document.getElementsByClassName("placeholder");
//toggle between 'add a list' and 'add another list' links
window.onload = function(){
   spans[1].style.display='none';
   document.forms[0].style.display='none';
};

let clicked = 0;
//toggle between links and 'add-list-form'
function toggleDiv(formId, linkId){
  clicked++;
  if(document.getElementById( formId ).style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementById( formId ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( linkId ).style.display = 'block';
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById( linkId ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( formId ).style.display = 'block'
  }if(clicked > 0) {
    spans[0].style.display='none';
    spans[1].style.display='block';
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName('')

//toggle between links and 'add-list-form'
function hideSHowForm(form, link, id){
  // var getForm = document.getElementsByClassName("listContainer");

    
    // getForm[i].style.display = 'block';
      if(document.getElementsByClassName(form)[id].style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementsByClassName(form)[id].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(link).style.display = 'block';
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById(link).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName(form)[id].style.display = 'block'
  }if(clicked > 0) {
    spans[0].style.display='none';
    spans[1].style.display='block';
  }
}
// function showTitleAndCardSection(){
//   var showCardSection = document.getElementsByClassName("listContainer");
//   for (var i=0;i<showCardSection.length;i+=1){
//     showCardSection [i].style.display = 'block';
//   }
```

```css
/*************** ADD LISTS ***************/

.work-board {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#list-wrapper {
  margin: 8px 5px 10px 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list {
  background: transparent;
}

.list-container {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 256px;
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
  border: none;
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.list-heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.list .list-heading h3 {
  margin: 2px 3px 0px 0px;
  width: 82%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline:none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
}

.list .list-heading h3:focus{
  border: solid 2px   rgb(91,164,207);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.ellipsis {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.ellipsis:hover {
  background-color: rgba(131, 140, 145, 0.2)
}

form.add-item-form .ellipsis{
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  /* line-height:3px;  */
  text-align:center;
}

form#add-list-form { 
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 270px;
}

.form-inner-container {
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=text] {
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px   rgb(91,164,207);
  width: 247px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px   rgb(91,164,207);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 8px 13px;
  background-color: rgb(90, 172, 68);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(63, 111, 33);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 138, 53);
}

input[type=button]{
  margin-right: -5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
}

input[type=button]:hover{
  color: rgb(103,109,112);
}

form.add-item-form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

form.add-item-form textarea {
  outline: none;
  width: 92%;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.card {
  width: 92%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  min-height: 18px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}
.card:hover {
  background-color: rgba(248,249,249,0.7);
}
.card p{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card a{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fa-pen {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.fa-pen:hover {
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
}

#add-list-form, .add-item-form {
  display: none;
}

.link-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a#show-list-form {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  width: 242px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 17px;
}

a#show-list-form:hover {
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.4);
}

a#show-list-form span:first-child {
  padding-right: 172px;
}

a#show-list-form span:nth-child(2), a#show-card-form span:nth-child(2){
  display: none;   /* hides the 'Add another link' when window loads */
}
```

```html
<div class="board-wrapper">
    <div id="workBoard" class="work-board">
      <div id="list-wrapper"></div>
      <div class="link-wrapper">
        <a href="#" id="show-list-form" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');">
        <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a list</span>
        <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another list</span>
      </a>
      </div>
      <form id="add-list-form">
        <div class="form-inner-container">
        <input type="text" id="list-name" placeholder="Enter list title..." autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" value="Add List">
        <!-- <input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></input> -->
        <input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form')" value="&#88;">
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end of board-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're saying about revising the code. I will look into it at a later time but for now, this is how I know to do it.  As for your code, it does not provide me with the answer I'm looking for. It actually adds a form to each list which is not what I want. Also, I'm not able to close the form anymore with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines above your `const list = document.createElement('div');` line inside your `addList()` function like this:

```
var listWrap = document.getElementById("list-wrapper");
listWrap.innerHTML = "";
```

What the above does is assign the `list-wrapper` div to a variable called `listWrap` and then reset the `list-wrapper` div to an empty div whenever someone tries to submit a new form. After emptying the `list-wrapper` div, the function then proceeds to add the new "add-item-form form" submitted to the empty `list-wrapper` div.

---

Run the **Code Snippet** below to see how the above two lines work:

```js
// *************** ADD LISTS ***************

// add new list submit eventlistener
document.getElementById("add-list-form").addEventListener("submit", addList);

function addList(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const input = document.getElementById("list-name");
  const name = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  if ('' == name) {
    return;
  }

  var listWrap = document.getElementById("list-wrapper");
  listWrap.innerHTML = "";

  const list = document.createElement('div');
  list.setAttribute('class', 'list');
  list.innerHTML =
    `<div class="list-container">
    <div class="list-heading" >
      <h3 contenteditable="true">` + name + `</h3>
    <div class= "ellipsis"><a href="#">&#8230;</a></div>
    </div>
      <div> 
      <div class="link-wrapper">
      <a href="#" id="show-card-form" onclick="hideSHowForm('add-item-form', 'show-card-form');">
      <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a card</span>
      <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another card</span>
    </a>
    </div>
        <form class="add-item-form">
          <textarea placeholder="Enter a title for this card..."></textarea>
          <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Card">
          <input type="button" value="&#88;" onclick="hideSHowForm('add-item-form', 'show-card-form');">
          <div class= "ellipsis"><a href="#">&#8230;</a></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>`;

  document.getElementById("list-wrapper").appendChild(list);
}

// add new item submit eventlistener
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.add-item-form')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const textarea = e.target.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    const text = textarea.value;
    textarea.value = '';
    if ('' == text) {
      return;
    }
    //create card
    const cardItem = document.createElement('p');
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
    //create pen icon
    const pen = document.createElement('a');
    pen.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pen"></i>';
    cardItem.innerHTML = text;
    card.appendChild(cardItem)
    card.appendChild(pen);
    e.target.parentElement.prepend(card);
  }
});

let spans = document.getElementsByClassName("placeholder");
//toggle between 'add a list' and 'add another list' links
window.onload = function(){
   spans[1].style.display='none';
   document.forms[0].style.display='none';
};

let clicked = 0;
//toggle between links and 'add-list-form'
function toggleDiv(formId, linkId){
  clicked++;
  if(document.getElementById( formId ).style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementById( formId ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( linkId ).style.display = 'block';
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById( linkId ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( formId ).style.display = 'block'
  }if(clicked > 0) {
    spans[0].style.display='none';
    spans[1].style.display='block';
  }
}



//toggle between links and 'add-list-form'
function hideSHowForm(form, link){
  // var getForm = document.getElementsByClassName("listContainer");
  for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName(form).length;i++){
    // getForm[i].style.display = 'block';
      if(document.getElementsByClassName(form )[i].style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementsByClassName(form)[i].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(link).style.display = 'block';
  }else{ 
    document.getElementById(link).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName(form)[i].style.display = 'block'
  }if(clicked > 0) {
    spans[0].style.display='none';
    spans[1].style.display='block';
  }
  }
}
// function showTitleAndCardSection(){
//   var showCardSection = document.getElementsByClassName("listContainer");
//   for (var i=0;i<showCardSection.length;i+=1){
//     showCardSection [i].style.display = 'block';
//   }
//}
```

```css
/*************** ADD LISTS ***************/

.work-board {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#list-wrapper {
  margin: 8px 5px 10px 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.list {
  background: transparent;
}

.list-container {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 256px;
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
  border: none;
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.list-heading {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.list .list-heading h3 {
  margin: 2px 3px 0px 0px;
  width: 82%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline:none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
}

.list .list-heading h3:focus{
  border: solid 2px   rgb(91,164,207);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.ellipsis {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.ellipsis:hover {
  background-color: rgba(131, 140, 145, 0.2)
}

form.add-item-form .ellipsis{
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  /* line-height:3px;  */
  text-align:center;
}

form#add-list-form { 
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 270px;
}

.form-inner-container {
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=text] {
  height: 32px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px   rgb(91,164,207);
  width: 247px;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px   rgb(91,164,207);
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 8px 13px;
  background-color: rgb(90, 172, 68);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(63, 111, 33);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 138, 53);
}

input[type=button]{
  margin-right: -5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
}

input[type=button]:hover{
  color: rgb(103,109,112);
}

form.add-item-form {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

form.add-item-form textarea {
  outline: none;
  width: 92%;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  resize: none;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.card {
  width: 92%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  min-height: 18px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
}
.card:hover {
  background-color: rgba(248,249,249,0.7);
}
.card p{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card a{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 220px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fa-pen {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.fa-pen:hover {
  background-color: rgb(226,228,230);
}

#add-list-form, .add-item-form {
  display: none;
}

.link-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

a#show-list-form {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  width: 242px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 17px;
}

a#show-list-form:hover {
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.4);
}

a#show-list-form span:first-child {
  padding-right: 172px;
}

a#show-list-form span:nth-child(2), a#show-card-form span:nth-child(2){
  display: none;   /* hides the 'Add another link' when window loads */
}
```

```html
<div class="board-wrapper">
    <div id="workBoard" class="work-board">
      <div id="list-wrapper"></div>
      <div class="link-wrapper">
        <a href="#" id="show-list-form" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');">
        <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a list</span>
        <span class="placeholder"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another list</span>
      </a>
      </div>
      <form id="add-list-form">
        <div class="form-inner-container">
        <input type="text" id="list-name" placeholder="Enter list title..." autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" value="Add List">
        <!-- <input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form');"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></input> -->
        <input type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('add-list-form', 'show-list-form')" value="&#88;">
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end of board-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thanks but you edited the _add List form_ (add-list-form) but that's not the form I want to edit, I am supposed to be able to create multiple lists. I want to edit the _add card form_ i.e. the form with class = "add-item-form" and the **Add card** button.